# Why the added list is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am using python3.9.7 on linux and I met a strange error today when i am doing my algorithm *permutations*.The error is that the added list is empty.
To be more specific,here is the `code`:

```py
class Solution:
    def permute(self, nums):
        def backtrace(nums, tmpResult, level):
            if nums == []:
                print(f"{level}: {tmpResult}")
                res.append(tmpResult)
                return
            for i, v in enumerate(nums):
                tmpResult.append(v)
                level += 1
                backtrace(nums[:i] + nums[i + 1 :], tmpResult, level)
                level -= 1
                tmpResult.pop()

        res = []
        tmpResult = []
        backtrace(nums, tmpResult, 1)
        print(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Solution().permute([1, 2, 3])
```

and the `result`:

```py
4: [1, 2, 3]
4: [1, 3, 2]
4: [2, 1, 3]
4: [2, 3, 1]
4: [3, 1, 2]
4: [3, 2, 1]
[[], [], [], [], [], []]
```

and if I `change` the `line 6` to `res.append(repr(tmpResult))`,the `result` is:

```py
4: [1, 2, 3]
4: [1, 3, 2]
4: [2, 1, 3]
4: [2, 3, 1]
4: [3, 1, 2]
4: [3, 2, 1]
['[1, 2, 3]', '[1, 3, 2]', '[2, 1, 3]', '[2, 3, 1]', '[3, 1, 2]', '[3, 2, 1]']
```

Could someone tell me why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a reference to the `tmpResult` list to `res`. `tmpResult` ends up as an empty list, so the final result shows you a list of 6 of those empty lists. You should append a copy of the list instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/12123296

Line 6 should be something like `res.append(tmpResult.copy())`.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you copy à list and change the original list after the copy will change as well:
[List changes unexpectedly after assignment. Why is this and how can I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/12744275)

To avoid it you can replace
res.append(tmpResult)

By
res.append(tmpResult.copy())
Or by
res.append([x for x in tmpResult] )